# Searching an arraylist for an object using a String which acts an an object ID? Null pointer issues

Tags: java, string, arraylist, nullpointerexception

When searching for a book in a book store, say the object is a book, each book object would have a title, author, ISBN code etc.

Say I enter an ISBN as a `String` using `scan.next()'

I take this input and use it to find the object in the arraylist as follows:

```
public Book searchISBN (String givenISBN){
    Book foundBook = null;
    for(Book findISBN : bookStore){
        if(findISBN.getISBN().equals(givenISBN)){//edit changed this to inc. !=null as suggested
            foundBook = findISBN;}
    }    
    return foundBook;
```

I do not understand why this is. When I include the following piece of code, which has the aim of setting any book that has a null classification equal to a specified classification:

```
            if(selectedBook.getISBN().equals(null)){...
```

I get a null pointer exception if I run with the above line of code in. There is a warning at this line stating 'object equals null is never true', in the class that creates the book object `String ISBN = null`, as the intention is to set a value for this in a different class which creates objects for the book store where half the books in my collection are set an ISBN. The other half are meant to be set ISBNs if they equal null (in the main method

No idea what to do with this.

As the problem may be with the get method, it is just this:

```
//the Book constructor has ISBN = null
public String getISBN(String givenClass){
    return ISBN
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a NullPointerException at this line probably is because the reference is null and you can't call a method on a null reference.

```
if(selectedBook.getISBN().equals(null)){....
```

The warning instead is due to the fact that you are using the equals() method to check against null. You should use ==

```
if(selectedBook.getISBN() == null)){....
```

Now without the relevant code it's not clear exactly the logic behind your program. I'll try to describe 2 possible scenarios.

1. assuming that the selectedBook reference can be null there's no need to check if the ISBN is null. You would simply check the reference.

   ```
   if(selectedBook == null){....// your logic here
   ```
2. In case a newly created Book can have a ISBN = null as it looks from your description and you are assigning the value of ISBN in another class if I understood what you are saying, why don't you simply set the ISBN to a default value?

   ```
   String ISBN = "undefined"
   ```

   And then perform a check

   ```
   if(selectedBook.getISBN().equals("undefined"){....// your logic here
   ```

Lastly let me point out that in this snippet of code

```
//the Book constructor has ISBN = null
public Book getISBN(String givenClass){
    return ISBN
}
```

ISBN seems to be of type Book, not String as you mentioned at the beginning of your post,but as said without seeing the rest of your program is not clear what's happening exactly.

Hope that was clear.

Comment: changed to == and seems to be working better, the problem now is that the `findISBN` class must return a Book object, so in the case where an ISBN that doesn't exist is entered, a book with the ISBN null is returned. Further, if in later stages that same book that is returned is then assigned ISBN, it will still be returned when a ISBN that doesn't exist is searched. Also, the Book ISBN was a mistake on my part, I just wrote it in as opposed to copying and pasting it, fixed it now

Comment: @Maitiu :you meant the seachISBN method, didn't you? In your original post findISBN is not a class, it's a variable of type Book defined in the for loop within the searchISBN method. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, `searchISBN` method must return a Book object is what I meant to say.

Comment: Ok. When you set the ISBN on a book that did not have it, do you put it back in the bookStore collection? Keep in mind that you cannot edit items in a collection with an enhanced for loop, you need to use the for loop that uses an index or an iterator if the bookStore is  of type List

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your getISBN() function is returning null. And yes, a newly created string object will never be null. You can check if the returned value is null by `if(findISBN.getISBN()!=null && findISBN.getISBN().equals(givenISBN))` .

Comment: Still having issues, eg when I search with the ISBN, some books a returned that have an ISBN = null. Also I still need to comment out the `if(selectedBook.getISBN().equals(null)){...` which aims give isbn to book which haven't got one. If I don't comment it out it won't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your get your getISBN() might be returning null,  do a null check before that if condition .  `if(findISBN.getISBN()!=null`.

Comment: Still having issues, eg when I search with the ISBN, some books a returned that have an ISBN = null. Also I still need to comment out the `if(selectedBook.getISBN().equals(null)){...` which aims give isbn to book which haven't got one. If I don't comment it out it won't run at all.